# Vaadin 14 show simple HTML Page

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, vaadin14

I made some kind of internal manual for a webapp that i am developing. I am using Spring Boot and Vaadin 14. How to implement a button that shows that document? The html doc is in my resources folder. I wonder if i am stupid. Or should i write my own controller for this?

Comment: Do you want to redirect the user to a separate browser tab / page, or show the document inside your Vaadin UI, or something else?

Comment: It does not matter, A new page is okay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Vaadin application itself is a single dynamic HTML page.

The easiest way to include HTML formatted content (not an HTML document) is to use the `Html` component.

```
Html html = new Html("<div><h3>Title</h3><p><b>Bold summary text</b></p><p>Other text</p></div>");
layout.add(html);
```

Note, when you use the `Html` component, you need to strip the `<head>` and `<body>` tags, as `Html`'s purpose is not to show full HTML documents. The `Html` component's content should be included inside a single root element - usually a `<div>` is used for this purpose.

However, based on your use case, I think the `Html` component will serve you well.

Comment: Thanks Tatu now i must change my html to be compliant